# А существует ли инкапсуляция, если есть рефлексия?

Tags: java, c++, ооп, рефлексия

В принципе весь вопрос в заголовке.
Получается, что одной из главных задач инкапсуляции и нету вовсе, а именно сокрытие методов или полей объекта от нежелательного использования злоумышленниками.

Comment: В C++ тоже существует рефлексия?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - нет, но там есть другая запарка с указателями.

Comment: Часть про злоумышленников вы на самом деле придумали сами. Инкапсуляция не предотвращает доступ, а убирает из области видимости те вещи, которые не нужны пользователю того или иного функционала.

Comment: Что же, я знаю множество моментов, в которых инкапсуляция была использована как мера защиты, но рефлексия напрочь убирает эту защиту, конкретные примеры - дыры в Android

Comment: Слушайте, ну честно. Ну вот хоть немного логики. Если X используется для Y, то разве это значит, что X и Y одно и то же? Есть люди, которые любят на других людях покататься, я ж не средство передвижения теперь.

Comment: @Etki, не придумал он.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это ещё хуже. Значит, придумали те, кто так утверждает.

Comment: @VladD, посмотри мой ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, я именно про это. Если надо загрузить чужой код в свой процесс, для этого выделяют специальный домен без FullTrust. (А лучше [отдельный хост-процесс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), конечно).

Answer (score 11):

Цель инкапсуляции — подсказка разработчику, чем можно, а чем не стоит пользоваться. Какие данные предназначены для чтения или изменения, а какие вовсе нет. Какие данные являются «контрактом», гарантированы, а какие нет. Что нужно знать об объекте, а на что не тратить серые клетки.

Цель инкапсуляции — вовсе не безопасность. Вы не можете защититься таким образом от злонамеренного программиста, который может воспользоваться декомпилятором Java-кода, узнать бинарный layout вашего объекта, и сделать что угодно с ним из нативного кода. Или выполнить `reinterpret_cast` в C++, и проанализировать, а то и поменять байты вашего объекта.

Для защиты от враждебного кода существуют другие средства. В .NET это, например, загрузка его в AppDomain с урезанными правами, в котором запрещена рефлексия, вызов нативного кода и функции наподобие [`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Да, существует.

Потому что инкапсуляция имеет смысл только если объект рассматривается как черный ящик: у типа есть определенный публичный контракт, а все внутренности (детали реализации) спрятаны (инкапсулированы). Клиенты используют контракт, не зная о том, как оно работает внутри.

Применяя рефлексию, вы уже не рассматриваете объект как черный ящик. Потому что вы уже заглянули вовнутрь и посмотрели, что и как вам надо дернуть и к какому приватному полю обратиться. С использованием публичного контракта это имеет мало что общего.

Comment: Я так-то имел ввиду конкретную часть инкапсуляции, а именно защищённость, что касательно грамотного кода, тот тут вопросов нету,   инкапсуляция работает

Comment: @BORSHEVIK против лома, как известно, нет приема.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже было подмечено отвечающими, инкапсуляция связана с безопасностью очень опосредовано - как возможный механизм сокрытия данных и реализации.
Это всего-лишь очень полезный паттерн, который как бы проводит границу полномочий и ответственностей - то, что внутри черного ящика вас не должно касаться и лучше вам в него не лезть. Все, что вас должно волновать - интерфейс, который этот ящик реализует, пользуйтесь им на здоровье.

Ну и с чисто исторической и не только точки зрения - это еще способ "не пересекаться случайно именами". Представьте, что у вас нет поддержки пространств имен и возможности объединять логические структуры в классы/объекты/что-то еще, т.е. где любые данные (читай, переменные) глобальны - программировать в такой среде очень опасно и чревато коллизиями. Как я понимаю, для этого в том числе используется инкапсуляция, но как и в случае с безопасностью - это вторичный результат.

Answer (score 3):

Про инкапсуляцию и рефлексию ответили достаточно полно, единственное, хотелось бы добавить, что рефлексия - не единственное, чем можно нарушить/обойти инкапсуляцию. Достаточно вспомнить передачу объекта "по ссылке" и "по значению".

Давайте рассмотрим простой блок кода: Пусть есть класс **A**:

```
public class A {
   private List<String> privateList;

   public A(List<String> privateList) {
      this.privateList = privateList;
   }

   public List<String> getPrivateList() {
      return privateList;
   }
}
```

Казалось, бы, все вполне стандартно, но что тут не так?

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("Меня передадут в коструктор");
A myObj = new A(myList);
myList.add("Так мы изменили состояние приватного поля экземпляра класса A");
myList.add("И даже не использовали рефлексию");
myObg.getPrivateList().add("Так тоже меняется приватное поле");
```

С одной стороны - мы не нарушили принципов инкапсуляции (вызывали только публичные - видимые для нас методы), с другой - состояние приватного поля изменилось.

Таким образом, делаем вывод, в полной мере "из коробки" в привычном для нас виде инкапсуляция в Java работает только для неизменяемых (immutable) объектов, таких как примитивы (`byte, short, int`), строки и т.п. 
Для изменяемых (mutable) объектов необходимо возвращать их копии.

```
public class A {

   private List<String> privateList;

   public A(List<String> privateList) {
      this.privateList = new ArrayList<>(privateList);
   }

   public List<String> getPrivateList() {
      return new ArrayList<>(privateList);
   }

}
```

Статья по этой теме на DZone: https://dzone.com/articles/encapsulation-i-dont-think-it-means-what-you-think

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как в джаве, но в C# для обращения к приватным сущностям, код, использующий рефлексию, должен выполняться с полным доверием (FullTrust). Не разбирался, как оно детально работает, но есть возможность убрать полное доверие для потенциально зловредного кода (например, плагинов). У Эрика Липерта есть несколько постов, касающихся предотвращения злонамеренного воздействия из кода, однако, в тех, которые я читал, уже предполагалось, что тот код не обладает FullTrust-возможностями и пытается "навредить" штатными средствами.