# Обход рефлексией инкапсуляции в Java. Зачем это сделано?

Tags: java, ооп, рефлексия, инкапсуляция

С помощью Java Reflection API есть способ обратиться к `private` полю класса, т.е. способ обхода одного из основных принципов ООП.

И у меня возник простой вопрос: зачем давать возможность так делать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [А существует ли инкапсуляция, если есть рефлексия?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454830/%d0%90-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Чтобы сделать сериализацию/десериализацию объекта. Без нарушения инкапсуляции трудно сохранить объект в файл и восстановить его из файла.

Comment: См. также [Dosen't Reflection API break the very purpose of Data encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635025/)

Comment: Например реализоавать фреймворк, где в конфиге ты описываешь всё что тебе надо, а тот автоматически из конфигурационных описаний компилит полноценное работающее приложение за счёт DI и прочей магии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо присвоить значение `private` полю, то для этого надо писать `public` геттерры/сеттеры или конструктор инициализатор. Если таковых нет, то изменить значение поля со стороны нельзя, за исключением если использовать Reflection API. Это не отменяет инкапсуляцию, поскольку с помощью рефлексии можно отменить/применить ограничения Java, но это используется для *внутреннего* инженеринга. Программист всегда может отменить/запретить рефлексию, поскольку она не является нормальным способом написания програм.

> `...способ обхода одного из основных принципов ООП`

Нет, Reflection API  не меняет *цель* инкапсуляции данных.  Цель инкапсуляции данных остается прежней... даже если кто-то умышленно нарушает ее.

---

Reflection API можно применить где угодно, наиболее часто используется при написании тестов, когда требуется снять ограничения инкапсуляции для доступа к private полю. Потому, что код написан другим программистом и нет другого способа изменить поведение программы, а также покрытие. Но это не значит, что код из тестов можно использовать для реализации рабочей программы.